# analytical function

Tags: complex-analysis

Could someone please provide a step by step explanation of the following exercise?  Determine the largest open set where f is analytic.$ f(z)=|x^2−y^2|+2i|xy|$

this right? Please I need help to finish it, I don't know what to do?

1. $f(z) = x^2 - y^2 + 2i |xy| $
   $ u = x^2 - y^2 $
   $ v = 2i $ $xy $

$\frac{2u}{2x}= 2x $ , $ \frac{2v}{2y} = 2x$

$\frac{2u}{2y}= -2y$

$\frac{2v}{2x} = 2y $

$\frac{2u}{2x} = \frac{2v}{2y}$

$\frac{2u}{2y} = -\frac{2v}{2x}$
Is correct ?

Comment: I think you should try doing cases and applying the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: I mean, isn't that right? can you help me please?? I need it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$: We can write the function piecewise by recognizing that it can take on four different forms

$$f(z) = \begin{cases}z^2 \\ \bar{z}^2 \\ -z^2 \\ -\bar{z}^2\end{cases}$$

depending on which "slice" of the complex plane we are on. The absolute values divide the plane into eight equal slices, and the only ones that the function can be analytic on are the ones where the function is either $z^2$ or $-z^2$. Can you take it from here?